# Autowired spring annotation on method with multiple arguments

Tags: java, spring, methods, dependency-injection, autowired

I know that I can use Autowired annotation on method.

for example:

```
    @Autowired
    public void someMethod(Object obj1, MyObj obj2, AnotherClass obj3, TestClass obj4){...}
```

What rules uses at this case?

```
obj1 obj2 obj3 obj4
```

should be in context?

or only one?

or nothing

Can I specified it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what your specific question is?

Comment: @geoffreydv What does it mean this code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All method arguments should be resolvable by the application context. You can also use `@Qualifer` annotation to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: In another case I will get Exception?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, you will get a `No qualifying bean of type [XXX] found for dependency...`

Comment: Is way to avoid this exception for concrete parameter?

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can use `@Value` on a method parameter to specify a default value or `require="false"` to skip the method call if there are some missing parameter.

Comment: 1.require="false" - is it for all arguments only?   | 2. if I use Value annotation for argument and it doesn't found in context I don't get exception and in method uses value from this annotation but if this bean(argument of methof) exist in context all works under the old?

Comment: @gstackoverflow 1. require is for the Autowire annotaiton, just ignore instead throw expection. 2. Not really, it will use the supplied value in any cases.

Comment: No, If you want to override an actually autowired bean (the default) you have two options: use @Primary annotation or override the current bean definition with your own version.